# saving mapping fields

Tags: database

I have just saved fields for exporting to a new saved mapping field, but it is not coming up as an option when I go back into the database and try to export the same details for another group. I'm clicking "done" after chosing to save the mapping field so I don't know why it doesn't then appear as an option.

Comment: Please edit your question to state your CiviCRM version and your CMS (Drupal/WordPress/Joomla/Backdrop)?

Answer (score 1):

1.Check if the actual mapping is saved - /civicrm/admin/mapping?reset=1

(Tip – Mappings only get saved/updated once you physically hit the export button)

2.The use a saved field mapping, the drop down will only appear if you select the “Select fields for export"

[image]

Comment: also wouldn't the mapping only be available if you are exporting from the same 'entity' eg from Contacts for a Contacts mapping, or Memberships for a Members mapping